# Can Gitlab-CI runner work with MacOSx and docker to publish in app store?

Tags: macos, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, continuous-delivery

I am thinking to host a `MacOSX` device for building and distributing the application in the Mac Application Store.

I would prefer to run the gitlab-runner instance using a docker container, and if possible, deploy it with marathon by distance.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I built native apps you needed native OS X for using the necessary tools like app signing and such. Building in a docker container is not native OS X, so that would not be possible, and Marathon is then also out of the question.

But..using a GitLab runner with the Shell executor on Mac OS should work! You can run all Mac tools (if they don't need an interactive window)

If you are using hybrid apps (React Native for instance https://github.com/ptmt/react-native-macos) you  can build apps for 90% anywhere, but it becomes tricky when you need to sign stuff again.. But here are services like http://www.macincloud.com where you rent a Mac for a while!

Comment: So running a docker container that give full access to the host to run command from gitlab-ci is totally possible. Your answer look like a NO. If I have a friend who have marathon and a mac on my network, I can deploy a container on he's host, and perform the build from GitLab using GitLab-CI.

Comment: You seem to know the answer, why ask the question?

Comment: I havent trier and I am not sur 100%. I am still looking for a mac but thats still 3000euro.

Comment: Currently it is possible to run native os x as docker container, that could theoretically work.. https://github.com/Cleafy/sxkdvm.  But I am not sure Apple allows this